# iOS - how to represent hierarchical data as master/detail template with 2 scenes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, design-patterns

I have a set of data that is basically a table of contents

1. First Section
  1. First Subsection
    1. First Subsection Content A
    2. First Subsection Content B
  2. Second Subsection
    1. Second Subsection Content A
    2. Second Subsection Content B
2. Second Section
  1. First Subsection
    1. First Subsection Content A
    2. First Subsection Content B
  2. Second Subsection
    1. Second Subsection Content A
    2. Second Subsection Content B

I would like the Master view to be able to handle displaying data at levels 
1, 1.1, 1.2

I would like the Detail view to be able to display the details for items at levels
1.1.1, 1.1.2

So, the first UITableView would show 2 items

---

First Section
Second Section

---

When someone clicks on "First Section" I would like to trigger a push that reloads the same Master view with data represented by the subsequent level in the tree.  The next section would then show the headings for 1.1 and 1.2

---

First Subsection
Second Subsection

---

When someone clicks on "First Subsection" I would like to trigger a push that reloads the same Master view with data represented by the subsequent level in the tree.  The next section would then show the headings for 1.1.1 and 1.1.2.

---

First Subsection Content A
First Subsection Content B

---

When someone clicks on "First Subsection Content A" I would like to trigger a push to the Detail view that loads content related to that heading.

Is this possible?  Is there a best practice that warns against this setup?  The goal here is to have a single Master view for any listing of branch nodes, and to single Detail view for viewing leaf nodes.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Bit confused by your terminology. You are saying push and reload in the same sentence for a single action. The usual interface for this sort of data is when tapped you push a new view controller onto the stack with the "more detailed" information.

If thats not what you are looking to do I wonder how one would go back whenever any of these items are selected if you just reload the current table?

Comment: it's more of a branch/leaf viewer that I'm after instead of a master/detail viewer.  Each branch will either contain another set of sub branches, or a set of leaf nodes.  When the user clicks a branch node, I would like it to reload the branch view with the new set of branches.  When the user clicks a leaf node, I would like to take them to the leaf node viewer (Detail view) and display the relevant data.  I appreciate your point about navigation and it's one I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do so.

Please check the code here> http://code.google.com/p/sugartin-info/downloads/detail?name=cellMaxMinDemo.zip&can=2&q=

It has the Folder structure view, which is quite nicely managed.

Comment: I think what I'm after is actually what's portrayed here.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

To properly answer this you would need to tell us how this data is arranged.
To do this, without regards to navigation or interface guidelines, you could generate a new array as your table datasource and then change that based on the users selection of a given table cell.

Say you have some sort of dictionary and array structure, you could build an array of the subsections (the children) of any section. Set that as your datasource and the reload the table view.